# Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python-2.7

While trying to install "lxml-3.1.0", I got the following error.

```
C:\Users\affine\Desktop\lib\lxml-3.1.0\src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(9) : 
    fatal  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h':
    No such file or directory
    error: command '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"'
    failed with exit status 2
```

Could someone help me understand this and overcome this issue?

Comment: I get the same problem on Windows 8. Did you figure it out?

Comment: actually this package developed based on visual studio 2008. even we given 2010 path it is not finding the page. so installed visual studio 2008 and then successfully installed this one.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to install `pyshark==0.3.3`for python2.7, there is an error with `xslt-config`. Its suggestion is to install VC++9.0 for python2.7. 
After downloading `Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7` from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266, I installed it. Then the similar error occurred:

> src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(14) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
>       Compile failed: command 'C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

So I install `lxml` in my windows command prompt using command `easy_install.exe lxml`in the directory of `G:\ProgramFiles\Python27\Scripts`like the following :

```
 G:\ProgramFiles\Python27\Scripts>easy_install.exe lxml
```

In the first time when I ran this command, it answered me time out. And then I ran it again, it did work.